# How do i select only visible objects in OBJECT mode

Tags: mesh, select

[image]I have a grid array of hundreds of small objects. there is a large mesh object in the middle of this grid array of smaller objects. i want to select only the small object on the outside of this larger mesh object. In object mode, using solid view, when i drag to select the small objects on the outside of the large mesh object, all small objects both inside and outside of the large mesh object are selected. how can i drag select and only select what is visible to me ie: on the outside of the mesh object? thanks.

Comment: provide screenshot?

Comment: I guess once you've selected, you need to choose another view and deselect the ones you don't want